# How does the following Underscore.js code work?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

*From the annotated source code:*

#### Create a safe reference to the Underscore object for use below.

```
 var _ = function(obj) {
    if (obj instanceof _) return obj;
    if (!(this instanceof _)) return new _(obj);
    this._wrapped = obj;
  };
```

I am having a hard time understand what did Jeremy mean by "creating a safe reference", and I am not 100% sure what that code is doing either.

Why not just do: `var _ = {}`? Where is the `obj` argument coming from and why do we have to check **instanceof**? Why returning using a **new** operator if it's not **instaneof**? And what is the purpose of the private variable **_wrapped**?

Comment: Underscore may also be called as a function that takes a set as its first argument, see http://underscorejs.org/#chaining

Comment: And `_.f(x)` can also be called as `_(x).f()` even without chaining in effect.

Comment: @muistooshort that's what I meant, the link is because of the clear example in the first part of that doc section.

Comment: The purpose of the private variable `wrapped` is to create a wrapped objects that underscore accesses in a few places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "safe reference", the author means a reference that won't be modified outside of the underscore closure.  Note that the underscore documentation also mentions that `has`<sup>[docs](http://underscorejs.org/#has)</sup> uses a "safe reference" to `hasOwnProperty`, "in case it's been overridden accidentally."

The code you asked about is motivated by behavior described in the [chaining](http://underscorejs.org/#chaining) docs.  Underscore supports two usage styles:

- Functional style: `_.isEmpty(obj)`
- Object-oriented style: `_(obj).isEmpty()`

The object-oriented style calls `_(obj)`, which returns a new `_` object, calling `_(obj)` again as a constructor.  When `_` is used as a constructor, `this` refers to the newly created object, so the last line of code executes, saving a reference to the value wrapped by the new `_` object.

In other words, `_` is a function, an object, and a constructor.